# How do I pass in an interface{} to a function as a specific structure?

Tags: go

I am trying to have a generic routine handle messages between specific components.  Part of this involves reading a byte array and using json.Marshal and json.Unmarshal and calling a callback.

I am trying to pass an interface to a function who expects a specific structure, but I do not know the type of the target structure.  In the code below, how does function r() call function cb() and pass in the correct data?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Bottom struct {
    Foo string
}

func cb(b *Bottom) {

    fmt.Println("5. ", b)
}

func r(t interface{}, buf []byte) {

    _ = json.Unmarshal(buf, &t)

    fmt.Println("2. ", reflect.TypeOf(t))
    fmt.Println("3. ", t)

    cb(&t)
}

func main() {
    x := Bottom{Foo: "blah"}
    var y Bottom

    buf, _ := json.Marshal(x)

    fmt.Println("1. ", x)
    r(&y, buf)
}
```

Comment: For example, in function r() if I change the line to say cb(t.(*Bottom)), the code works.  But in function r() I do not want to know about any specific type.

Comment: If `cb()` requires a `Bottom`, then all callers will need to know about the `Bottom` type. If your callers can't know about the `Bottom` type, then your `cb()` function should take in an interface that `Bottom` implements instead of a struct of type `Bottom`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to [use a type assertion](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions) to convert your `interface{}` to the type that your function requires. You can then add error checking to appropriately handle the case where your parameter can't be typecast to the desired type.

See this generic playground that demonstrates the solution: http://play.golang.org/p/NYeoAVTEeA

In your case, that means

```
cb(&t.(Bottom))
```

You can add error checking:

```
bottom, ok := t.(Bottom)
if !ok {
  // do something
}
cb(&bottom)
```

Comment: I would like to do it such that my function r() does not know about Bottom.

Comment: In that case you'll need to define an interface that `r()` does know about that `Bottom` implements, and have `cb` take in an instance of that interface instead of a parameter of type `Bottom`.